# Javascript getting variable from function for url

Tags: javascript

I need to add the users mouse/pointer vertical position to the url in a link

I have the following script.

```
 <script>
function show_coords(event)
{
var verticalPosition=event.clientY;
}
</script>
```

and then a link in the body of the page:

```
<a href="testplayer.cfm"
onclick="location.href='testplayer.cfm?play=ai-session3.mp3'+'&position='+verticalPosition;return false;">link</a>
```

this triggers a "`position=undefined`"

What is the correct syntax to include the vertical position in the url ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Debug the verticalPosition, probably the link is generated before handler is added.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function

```
show_coords(event){
    var verticalPosition = event.clientY;
}
```

You are setting a local variable that just exists within that function call. What you should do is something like this.

```
var verticalPosition;
show_coords(event){
    verticalPosition = event.clientY;
}
```

What I would really do is make your HTML like:

```
<a onclick="redirect()">link</a>
```

Then your javascript (which will have to be in a script tag) can be:

```
var verticalPosition;
show_coords(event){
    verticalPosition = event.clientY;
}

function redirect(){
    window.location='testplayer.cfm?play=ai-session3.mp3&position='+verticalPosition;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but neither of these suggestions worked. the first continued to give the undefined. The second never redirected to the location. It was though the link didn't exist.

Comment: Is your function show_coords(event) actually getting called anywhere? That needs to get called first in order to stop getting undefined errors.

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes:

```
<a href="testplayer.cfm"
onclick="location.href='testplayer.cfm?play=ai-session3.mp3'+'&position='+show_coords();return false;">link</a>

show_coords() { return event.clientY; }
```

The problem was that your variable verticalPosition wasn't global so the onClick event for the a tag couldn't read it, so the best way to overcome that is to return the value from the function and just call the function from the onCLick event.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong try this code

```
<a href="testplayer.cfm" id="testPlayer">link</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#testPlayer').click(function(e)
    {
        location.href='testplayer.cfm?play=ai-session3.mp3'+'&position='+show_coords(e);
        return false;
    });
});

function show_coords(event)
{
    return event.clientY;
}
</script>
```

Comment: if you change it to `onclick="clickTestPlayer(event)"` it should work. This is a good answer. Although, as written I think you could do without the show_coords function and just put `event.clientY` in there.

Comment: @nackjicholson: you are right but if he wants coordinates for another event then he also can use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function setUrl(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var href = event.target.href,
        yPos = event.clientY,
        url = href + "?play=ai-session.mp3&position=" + yPos;

    window.location.href = url;
  }
</script>

<a href="target.cfm" onclick="setUrl(event)">link</a>
```

Check out this:

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nackjicholson/zSzXu/)

It is a somewhat working version, although because it's not practical to change the location.href in a jsfiddle i just printed the results to the page. Hope it helps, good luck!